# error:'ddVehicleType' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist as 'ddVehicleType' that is in edit field. iam getting value from database when page load. but the error is coming like

```
 'ddVehicleType' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.Parameter name: value
```

my coding is,

```
while (reader.Read())
                        {       
                                ddVehicleType.SelectedValue = reader["VehicleId"].ToString();

                        }
```

design page,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddVehicleType" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="drop" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="VehicleType" DataValueField="VehicleId">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TAXIConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [VehicleId], [VehicleType] FROM [VehicleMaster] WHERE ([Status] = @Status)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Available" Name="Status" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: maybe make it :QueryStringParameter? as you are using a string

Answer (score 0):

instead of **while loop** use **if**
cause only one value can be selected for dropdown list not multiple.
so remove while loop

```
if (reader.Read())
{       
      ddVehicleType.SelectedValue = reader["VehicleId"].ToString();
}
```

**OR**

May be the

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
```

and

```
while (reader.Read())
{       
      ddVehicleType.SelectedValue = reader["VehicleId"].ToString();
}
```

value is not matching 
also in SQLAdapter your valu type parameter string is different than what you passing in code.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TAXIConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [VehicleId], [VehicleType] FROM [VehicleMaster] WHERE ([Status] = @Status)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Available" Name="Status" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```